# Time Elapsed Since Last Event by Group

Tags: r, time, grouping

I'm trying to accomplish what seems like a fairly simple task. I would like to know how far apart scoring events are in a sporting match. The complicating factor, apart from my own ignorance, is the fact that I would like this information for every match in my rather large dataset.

Here is some reproducible data simulating my problem:

```
data.frame(
 matchid = sample(seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1), size = 1000, replace = TRUE), 
 scoreTime = as.POSIXlt(Sys.time() - 1:1000)
       ) -> df
```

If I weren't concerned with this information for every match, then I know that I could just use the diff function and bit of code like:

```
diff(as.POSIXlt(df$scoreTime), 1)
```

I've had a crack at the plyr library, and I think that might hold my answer, but I just can't seem to get the output I'm looking for. After each recorded scoring event, I'd like to be able to generate a new column with the time that has elapsed since the last scoring event in that match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the [dplyr](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr) package:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(scoreTime) %>% group_by(matchid) %>%
       mutate(sinceLast = c(NA, diff(as.POSIXlt(scoreTime), 1)))
```

This means:

- `arrange(scoreTime)` sort it in increasing time (necessary if you're going to use `diff`)
- `group_by(matchid)` divide into groups based on the match (what you're looking for)
- `mutate(sinceLast = c(NA, diff(as.POSIXlt(scoreTime), 1)))` within each match, add a new column, called `sinceLast`, that describes the amount of time (in seconds) since the previous scoring event. Note that I had to add `NA` at the start (because for the first scoring event in a game, there *is* not "time since last score).

Comment: Thank you for both your fantastic code and your excellent explanation of its function. You have my deepest gratitude.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R:

```
> sapply(unique(df$matchid), function(x) diff(as.POSIXlt(df[df$matchid==x,]$scoreTime), 1)   )
[[1]]
Time differences in secs
  [1] -23  -1  -6 -12  -1  -7 -20  -7  -1  -4  -7 -17  -1  -4  -1  -6  -5  -1  -1 -10 -11  -1  -4  -8  -1  -3  -2 -10 -13  -3 -15
 [32]  -1  -1  -1  -4 -14 -12  -1 -48  -1 -13  -7  -2  -3  -7 -38  -8  -1 -25 -13  -8  -1  -9 -10  -7  -1 -18 -24  -9  -7  -4  -9
 [63]  -1  -1  -9 -15  -1  -2 -24 -14  -2 -12  -1 -15  -4 -17 -20 -14 -17  -1 -14 -10  -7  -1  -3 -50 -51 -11  -2  -3  -1  -1  -8
 [94] -10  -7  -2  -3 -18  -3 -18  -3  -2 -15 -14  -1 -10 -16  -1 -10 -12
attr(,"tzone")
[1] ""

[[2]]
Time differences in secs
  [1]  -3 -16  -9  -6  -4 -13  -8 -19  -6 -10  -8 -12  -6 -13  -6 -14 -41  -5 -37  -4  -3  -2  -4  -4 -12  -2 -10 -20  -8  -7  -3
 [32] -13 -20  -1  -1  -9 -16  -4  -2 -15  -7  -5  -1 -10 -11 -13  -6 -17 -27 -12 -13  -4  -5  -6 -10  -5  -2  -8 -11 -17  -5  -6
 [63] -13 -33 -19  -5 -24  -2  -1 -16 -11  -6  -1 -22  -6  -9  -6 -10 -16  -6  -2  -1  -3 -10  -4  -4 -11  -1  -8 -27  -1  -6 -25
 [94]  -5  -2  -2 -30 -14 -17 -17  -5
attr(,"tzone")
[1] ""

[[3]]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is basically the same to @ David Robinson. But, I used `lag()` instead of `diff()`. `lag()` generates NA for the first observation in each match in this case.

```
ana <- df %>%
        arrange(matchid, scoreTime) %>%
        group_by(matchid) %>%
        mutate(gap = scoreTime - lag(scoreTime))

ana 

   matchid           scoreTime     gap
1        1 2014-09-26 00:26:02 NA secs
2        1 2014-09-26 00:26:04  2 secs
3        1 2014-09-26 00:26:14 10 secs
4        1 2014-09-26 00:26:19  5 secs
5        1 2014-09-26 00:26:26  7 secs
6        1 2014-09-26 00:26:28  2 secs
7        1 2014-09-26 00:26:32  4 secs
8        1 2014-09-26 00:26:36  4 secs
9        1 2014-09-26 00:26:54 18 secs
10       1 2014-09-26 00:27:13 19 secs
```